# Can't install Silverlight Developer runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have installed VS 2010 professional with full installation in Windows 7.

I have installed Silverlight 5.0 separately.

When I create  silverlight application, it asks for installing silverlight Developer runtime.

> You need to install the latest Silverlight Developer runtime before creating a Silverlight project

After downloading the runtime when I tried to install  it prompted that

> newer version of Silverlight is already installed

So I cant install runtime and I cant create siverlight application.

I tried to install Silverlight 5 tools, but it ask to install service pack 1 for visual studio.
 Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK and Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK are already installed in the system. Why SDK does not include the developer runtime ?

What are the things do we need to develop a silverlight application ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Service Pack 1 needed for Silverlight 5.

I suggest to(based on my recent experience)

1. Uninstall everything "Microsoft Silverlight" that you have
2. Make sure SP1 installed
3. Install Silverlight 5 tools from here: http://www.silverlight.net/

Comment: can we create application of silverlight 3 with silverlight 4 sdk ?(backward compatibility like in MSWord 2010 can create .doc files)

Comment: No, you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 164):

I was getting the same error. The problem was that the link that Visual Studio was giving was for the 32 bit version, and I am running 64 bit. Some kind of error mentioning *that* when failing the install would have been nice...

Here is the link for the 64-bit version of Silverlight 5 developer tools:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229324

Comment: After my restart I searched to find this post again just so I could upvote!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am in the same boat as @DanielSchilling ... what a frustrating journey. Makes you twitch thinking of the issues that a client might have when trying to install Silverlight...

Comment: un-FN-believable. wasted a half day on this.

Comment: Thanks for digging this quick and simple solution up!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest fix is to uninstall then re-install the Silverlight developer runtime as shown below when executed from a console window (for the 64 bit version):

Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe /qu

Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe

Note that you need to wait for the silent uninstall to complete, so give it a couple minutes before executing the re-install.

By the way, this issue is affecting everyone that had a previous installation of the SL developer runtime installed and upgraded to Windows 8.1!!

Answer (score 3):

After installing a new version of Silverlight you have to install the "Developer" version, too. With this, You can open your projects in Visual Studio without any problem.

x86:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=146060

x64:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229324

Comment: Not quite right. You must not install new versions of non-developer Silverlight. If you get it as a stupid update you have to delete it and reinstall developer version. You can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Silverlight version 5 and then reinstall it using the link provided from visual studio.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link very useful

[Microsoft Silverlight release history](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing Silverlight 5, I had to install the [Silverlight 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7335):

Answer (score 0):

Service Pack 1 needed for Silverlight 5.

I suggest to(based on my recent experience)

Uninstall everything "Microsoft Silverlight" that you have
Make sure SP1 installed [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
Install Silverlight 5 tools from here: [SL5](http://www.silverlight.net/)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual studio 2013 and windows 10, make sure you debug/start your application with Microsoft internet explorer. Debugging with Edge will result in the following error message: Unable to load the Silverlight developer runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link for Visual Studio SP1 Installer

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Here is the link for Visual Studio SP1 Direct Download

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710

Feel your comfort

Or else Download Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate Version (Direct Link)

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247147

Answer (score -7):

If you install Visual Studio 2012 or (now) release version you will overwrite .NET Framework 4.0 with 4.5 and apps created with 4.0 will need to be upgraded. .NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement to 4.0 not a side-by-side.

Comment: You are incorrect. Apps "Created with 4.0" will run *perfectly fine* under 4.5, just as they are. The fact that 4.5 is an 'in-place' update over 4.0 has nothing to do with existing programs running just as they did, in 99.999% of cases.