# You need to install the latest silverlight developer runtime before opening silverlight project

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

When I open silverlight project in vs2010 it'll show me the dialogbox with error

`" You need to install the latest silverlight developer runtime before opening silverlight project"`

and provide me link `"go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060"` , while I already install this silverlight version.

Please help me to resolve this stuff.

Comment: Have you installed developer version or run-time version? can you confirm

Comment: Found solution here: [stackoverflow topic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638552/cant-install-silverlight-developer-runtime

Answer (score 12):

I had the similar problem.
Every time I tried to visit a link and install thing I got the same.
However, I asked colleagues and they suggested me to install things in the following order:

1. Uninstall everything that has name "Silverlight"
2. Install "Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011.msi"
3. Install "silverlight_5_sdk.exe"
4. Install "Silverlight5_Tools_SP1.exe"
5. Install "Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe"

I had all that packages downloaded in my company, so you will need to find them in internet by yourself. From what I've seen, they are all available. The only matter is direction of installation. This one helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked for me as well. Here are the links:2. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435 3. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359 4. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28358 5. (newest at the time of writing): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55359

Answer (score 3):

The good link for the last version of « Silverlight **Developer** Runtime » (Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe or Silverlight_Developer.exe) is :
http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=39597 (French link) 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39597 (English link)

The last auto-update of Silverlight just install the standard run-time version.

Answer (score 0):

In order to always find the latest update/install files for Silverlight Developer Runtime (especially the 64-bit version), you can go to the following link:

[Microsoft Silverlight Release History](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm)

On this page, click the link for the most current release (typically the first link under Silverlight 5).

Then click the link to the KB article for this release (eg. "KB4023307" or whatever the current KB is).

On the KB article, you should see methods to obtain the updates.  Click the link for the Microsoft Update Catalog (usually Method #2).  This will provide a list the appropriate entries from the update catalog.  Click the "Download" button for the Security Updates option.

You should now get a window with a list of download options.  Click the link to download the "silverlight_developer_x64_blah...blah.exe" version or any other download you may need.

This is a number of steps but the only way I have found to reliably download the current developer runtime for x64.